# secondary nic pass trough to qemu-kvm

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, nic

My hardware setup has 2 nics;
first nic is for root ubuntu, and I want my secondary nic only accessible by qemu-kvm (bridge for different VM's) without being seen by the host os.

I tried everything, but I always en up with 2 leases on my dhcp-server; one ip on NIC1 & and one on NIC2

So how can I make nic1 the interface for the root os, and nic 2 for all the vm's?